# Ansible multiple condition not working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible Version: 2.2.1.0

hostfile:

`[master]
    54.65.104.4
    [slaves]
    52.69.71.248`

tasks/main.yaml

```
 - name: Checking if the node is already having spark master installed (master)
   stat:
     path: /etc/init.d/spark-master
     register: spark-master
   when: inventory_hostname in groups['master']
 - name: Checking if the node is already having spark worker installed
   stat:
     path: /etc/init.d/spark-slave
     register: spark-slave
   when: inventory_hostname in groups['slaves']

  # Downloading to the master
 - include: download.yaml
   when: (inventory_hostname in groups['master']) and ( spark-master.stat.exists == false)

 # Downloading to the slaves
 - include: download.yaml
   when: (inventory_hostname in groups['slaves']) and ( spark-slave.stat.exists == False )
```

But when I execute the script I am receiving the following errors:

```
 fatal: [52.69.71.248]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check '(inventory_hostname in groups['slaves']) and ( spark-slave.stat.exists == False )' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ((inventory_hostname in groups['slaves']) and ( spark-slave.stat.exists == False )): 'slave' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/opt/ansible-role-spark/tasks/download.yaml': line 2, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n- name: Download Spark\n  ^ here\n"}
```

Can anybody help me in figuring the mistake I am committing.

Comment: Where is the `Download Spark` task which throws the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either quote the condition, like:

```
when: "(inventory_hostname in groups['master']) and ( spark-master.stat.exists == false)"
```

Or don't use parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The error in question is about:

> Variable names should be letters, numbers, and underscores.

See [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name).

But you have other design flaws in your playbook that are beyond this question.

Comment: yeah, there is design flaw in my playbook, although I have changed the variable names to have underscores.

Comment: I want to execute the `download.yml` on both master and slave if the init script is not present, but name of the init script is different in both the servers.